# Visual Studio Code not showing git changes for submodule

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I edit a file and hit save withing a Git submodule, the changes are not caught by Visual Studio Code. Is that expected behavior (I am experiencing the same using GitLens)?

I like how a "M" is added at the right of files in the main repo.

Comment: What do you mean by *"changes are not caught"*? No `M` to right of the file name in the explorer pane?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's it... looks like git features are not enabled within the submodule.

Comment: The SCM tabs does show changes in a submodule, and lets you make new commits in a submodule, so VSC definitely knows what they are.

Comment: Very strange... things are working as expected now... Looks like my issue could be related to https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/58.